# Whats the difference between installing a desktop from iso and apt-get?

Tags: apt, xubuntu, desktop-environments

So lets say I want to install Xubuntu. I can either go to their website and download an ISO, flash it to a memory stick and do an install, one of the options of which allows me to keep all my files and programs.

Or, I can type `sudo apt-get install xubuntu*` which will install all the xubuntu packages. What is the difference in what I get by these two methods and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you start from.

If you do a clean install of Xubuntu, only XFCE applications will be installed.

If you run

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

from already installed Ubuntu, you will keep all Unity applications.

That may get system slower and you will have too many similar programs installed.

But you will have an option to log in to Ubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Thats what I noticed by trial, I was wondering if there was anything else :) But if thats all then thats good, thank you